# Use summary data in row calulations on a report?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I am using Cognos Report Studio 8.4.1.

I have a list report where I want to use a query calculation to create a new column of data, but the calculation needs two numbers from the **summary** (subtotal) of the data I want to do the calculation for. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Sample data:

```
ID #    Project #    Reg     OT    Bonus    
2716    20130405     41.6    1.6
2716    20130412     38.9    0.0
2716    20130419     52.3   12.3
2716    20130426     47.0    7.0
2716    B03-1304                   $23.17
2716    B15-1304                    $1.51
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
2716                  4            $24.68
------------------------------------------
2717    20130405     39.9    0.0
2717    20130412     40.2    0.2
  (etc)
```

The query calculation I want to create for each line would be:

[Total(Bonus)] / [Count(Reg)] / (Reg) / 2 * (OT)  *(this does not actually work)*

So in the above example, the result for the first row of data would be:

24.68 / 4 / 41.6 / 2 * 1.6 = 0.12  (rounded)

Is there **any** way I can do this, or the equivalent?

Completely re-writing the report or creating a new report is fine. If the answer is complex (or uses SQL), please be detailed; I'm a novice user and entirely self-taught, so there are a large number of gaps in my knowledge of Cognos.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Cognos summary functions 
[Report Studio Summaries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cbi/v10r2m0/topic/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_cr_rptstd.10.2.0.doc/c_summaries.html?path=3_5_29_0_1#summaries) 
Or more detailed explanation in here: 
[Using the AT and FOR Options with Relational Summary Functions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/page125.html) 
Too your question, I think it should be something like this:

```
total([bonus] for [ID])/count([Reg] for [ID])/[Reg]/2*[ot] <br>
```

If for some reason, it does not give expected results, try to break the expression to smaller expressions (like total([bonus] for [ID])) and see if it gives you expected results.